# Run Wireguard Client on Proxmox Host

Tags: networking, wireguard, proxmox

I'm trying to setup a Proxmox installation as a client of an existing Wireguard's server in order to connect from outside my home network.

I followed this guide
https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Debian_11&p=wireguard&f=2

and then run

```
systemctl enable wg-quick@wg0.service
systemctl start wg-quick@wg0.service
```

but the status is Active: active (exited) and I never see any connection on the server side.

This is what I get after installing and configuring:

```
    root@algo:~# systemctl status wg-quick@wg0.service
● wg-quick@wg0.service - WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wg-quick@.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Wed 2023-10-25 12:58:25 CEST; 5min ago
       Docs: man:wg-quick(8)
             man:wg(8)
             https://www.wireguard.com/
             https://www.wireguard.com/quickstart/
             https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg-quick.8
             https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg.8
    Process: 777 ExecStart=/usr/bin/wg-quick up wg0 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 777 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 25ms

Oct 25 12:58:25 algo systemd[1]: Starting wg-quick@wg0.service - WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0...
Oct 25 12:58:25 algo wg-quick[777]: [#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
Oct 25 12:58:25 algo wg-quick[777]: [#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
Oct 25 12:58:25 algo wg-quick[777]: [#] ip -4 address add 12.187.257.16 dev wg0
Oct 25 12:58:25 algo wg-quick[777]: [#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
Oct 25 12:58:25 algo wg-quick[777]: [#] ip -6 route add ::/1 dev wg0
Oct 25 12:58:25 algo wg-quick[777]: [#] ip -6 route add 8000::/1 dev wg0
Oct 25 12:58:25 algo wg-quick[777]: [#] ip -4 route add 128.0.0.0/1 dev wg0
Oct 25 12:58:25 algo wg-quick[777]: [#] ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/1 dev wg0
Oct 25 12:58:25 algo systemd[1]: Finished wg-quick@wg0.service - WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0.
root@algo:~#
```

with wg I get this:

```
interface: wg0
public key: tgiehhoZKLHNCjebdsf64uyIgTUQNVJiXahPEYVBcH0k=
private key: (hidden) listening port: 58649
peer: 8bfBMSRm2emrzchft6356dgm2UggkPbeStfwE7UdLi4=
endpoint: 12.187.257.16:1194
allowed ips: 0.0.0.0/1, 128.0.0.0/1, ::/1, 8000::/1
transfer: 0 B received, 1.59 KiB sent
root@algo:~#
```

Here's the wg0.conf

```
[Interface]
# specify private key for client generated on WireGuard server
PrivateKey = XXXXXXXXXXXXX
# IP address for VPN interface
Address = 10.198.273.61

[Peer]
# specify public key for server generated on WireGuard server
PublicKey = XXXXXXXXXXXXX
# IP addresses you allow to connect
# on the example below, set WireGuard server's VPN IP address and real local network
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/1, 128.0.0.0/1, ::/1, 8000::/1
# specify server's global IP address:port
# (acutually, example of IP below is for private range, replace to your own global IP)
EndPoint = 103.16.54.18:1194
```

I don't get any errors but I don't see a connection on the server

Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

The same client configuration works correctly using Wireguard on Windows 11.

Thanks!

Comment: WireGuard does not use *connections*, it is based on UDP. Have you checked the VPN state with the `wg` command yet? Have you tried using the VPN link?

Comment: Make sure to [add all addition information to your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1814539/edit). You can use proper formatting there. // Like I said, connections aren’t a thing. Compare `wg` output on server and client: Do you see the expected public keys for all respective peers on all sides? Also, just to make sure, you _did_ add the client’s public key to the server configuration, right?

Comment: IIRC on Linux wg-quick only use its policy routing "magic" when you have `0.0.0.0/0` in an/the endpoint's AllowedIPs. The "magic" make sure the wg-encapsulated traffics would not be routed out of the wg interface again (i.e., loop). I'm not sure why you are using the openvpn-def1-like trick, but if you have a valid reason to, make sure you implement the "magic" yourself, or add a route for the endpoint's address.

Comment: Also, you seem to use the endpoint address as the wg interface address? (And that makes no sense.) It'd be better to share you wg-quick conf. (Feel free to omit/redact the keys.)

Comment: I've added the wg0.conf
I've also tried to change the AllowedIPs = to 0.0.0.0/0 on the client but I still can't get any connection

Comment: And once again I say: There are no connections. Please check my second comment above and see if you can answer my questions there.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the issue by using:
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0